Is it possible to switch between workspaces using Super+number?
Is it possible to switch between workspaces using Super+number?
I am on Ubuntu 22.04 and Super+number launch (or switch to an existing) application based on the application bar. I know it's possible to switch to a workspace using Super+PageDown but it takes too long when I have more than 3 workspaces. I don't mind a different hotkeys but that's what I used to because I was previously using i3, a tiled window manager. I find Gnome very good overall since I don't need to tweak basic things like bluetooth, volume, and brightness keys but managing windows can be a bit more efficient in my opinion.
Update: this bug persist on ubuntu 24.04.
Update: I didn't solve this but I found a fantastic workaround. I am using a Window Manager called https://regolith-desktop.com/ which uses i3 under the hood. I highly recommend it for people who loves i3 but also like the nice things Gnome offers. I now have workspaces and window + number jumps to the right workspace. Window+shift+number moves an application into that workspace, and Window+enter opens a new terminal. Life is good!
Thanks!

This can be achieved simply by going to Settings → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts → View and Customise Shortcuts and then down to Navigation. Go down the list to Switch to workspace 1 and set the key shortcut combination required Super+1 then continue with the other workspaces in the same way with the shortcuts required.


Thanks but even after changing them it doesn't work. super+number focuses on the APPLICATION (based on the order of the app in the application bar). Is there a way to disable that bar? I don't use it and currently it's hidden unless I moving my mouse close to the edge of my screen)

Update: it works with Ctrl + Number but not with Super...WHY? Also I only see the ability to change the keys for 4 workspaces. I have more than 4....

did you change the right navigation line? Did you select the one which is titled Move window to workspace 1 2, 3 or 4 as opposed to further down Switch to workspace 1,2,3 or 4? That certainly works as I described in the answer because I selected it and tested that it works before posting the answer...

You need to press  Super AND keypad number together then release. That's what I did to make it work.

I want to switch between workspaces so I choose the 4 'switch' options. Here is a screenshot that explains what's going on. When I hit Super+4, I see whatever workspace host the Firefox app because the Firefox is number 4 on the app bar at the bottom. This issue only happens with the Super key. With Ctrl it works perfectly.
Image: https://i.imgur.com/W30NamO.png (I can't embed it from some reason)

no idea what you have done but I just tried Super+4 with a FF open in workspace 1 and workspace 4 was presented with nothing in it as expected. I am using 22.04.4 using Wayland windowing system and English UK keyboard setting the 1-4 on the number keypad. My own testing showed that if you do not press Super and the appropriate number key on the numeric keypad together (not sequentially) then it won't work.

I use the default Ubuntu. Does it mean I don't use Wayland?

I am on Dvorak. Switching to Querty only worked for Super+1.

I just tried X11 on my instance and it still worked. Is the Dvorak keyboard layout specified in Settings > Keyboard? It might have helped to mention that in your original question to be honest. I don't see a Windows key on that layout - which key have you set as Super?

yes, I see Dvorak under keyboard settings. My super is the Window key on my laptop. That's the key between the left alt and the left ctrl.

I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 on X11 as I have an nVidia GPU.
I also have the bug where I cannot reassign the workspace switching to Super + N, with N being the number of the workspace.
As a workaround I am using the combination Super + Alt + N, which works fine, as well as Super + Alt + Shift + N to move windows between workspaces.

I am now using https://regolith-desktop.com/ and love it. It uses i3 under the hood.
